# JavaScript OnClick works only once

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am writing code to clear a particular input field but the button seems to clear it only once.

```html
<div class="input-field col s10">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">web</i>
  <input type="text" disabled name="pages-input" id="pages-input"></input>
</div>
<div class="col s2">
  <input type="button" class="waves-effect waves-light btn red white-text" onClick="document.getElementById('pages-input').setAttribute('value', '');" value="Clear" />
</div>
```

Comment: FYI there is no `</input>` tag. Inputs are self-closing. But your code works and does what you're asking it to. You can see it if you inspect the underlying code. However you probably want `.value=''` instead of `.setAttribute('value', '')`

Comment: `.setAttribute()` ?  Shouldn't it just be `.value = ''` ?

Comment: why not just use `<input type="reset">` and place all your form fields inside a `<form>` tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/develoger/fwpcjrcj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inputs are self closing and you must set the value differently.

```
<div class="input-field col s10">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">web</i>
  <input type="text" disabled name="pages-input" id="pages-input" />
</div>
<div class="col s2">
  <input type="button" class="waves-effect waves-light btn red white-text" 
    onClick="document.getElementById('pages-input').value = '';" value="Clear" />
</div>
```

Comment: Changed it to .value and also sorry about the closing of input tag, that was real foolish of me. But it clears teh field now then I am unable to enter anything in it after this. Also I use JS to add the value to the input from various functions like this.    function home_static() {
    pages.push("Static Home");
    //document.getElementById("pages").innerHTML = pages;
 document.getElementById("pages-input").setAttribute('value', pages);
 elements = pages.join(' ,')
 $.post('/quote-backend.php', {elements: elements})
}

Comment: Chnged that JS code to .value too. Working fine now thanks!